# HTML insert Image doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to insert an image in my HTML page but I always get this as result:

[image]

But I want to put this picture in my HTML page

[image]

This is the code:

```
<img id="avatar" width="100" height="100" src="image/avatar.jpg"/>
```

I also store the picture in my image folder.

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: This suggests the `src` you've supplied is incorrect. Are you certain that the image is at that path, relative to the page where it's referenced?

Comment: What kind of server do you use? A plain HTTP - server? Where are HTML-page and image located on server?

Comment: did you check if the directory 'image' can be read by your application? what happens when you type the entire url (yoursite.com/image/avatar.jpg) in the browser?

Comment: Right click the broken image and "Open Image in New Tab", and you'll see the URL of where the image is trying to be accessed from, so you can adjust accordingly.

Comment: It didn't work guys :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the path is generally correct, you need to add a `/` before the path, otherwise it's suggesting it's the path relative to your current page.

If you're currently at `example.com/page1` then

```
<img id="avatar" width="100" height="100" src="image/avatar.jpg"/>
```

is equivalent to `example.com/page1/images/avatar.jpg`

```
<img id="avatar" width="100" height="100" src="/image/avatar.jpg"/>
```

is equivalent to `example.com/images/avatar.jpg`

Notice I changed the `src` attribute to include a `/`

You should also try pasting the URL directly into your browser (after the domain) to check the image is accessible publicly.

Answer (score 0):

Initial `/` point to the root.

Try this `<img id="avatar" width="100" height="100" src="/image/avatar.jpg"/>`

Comment: Why would you answer with an less useful answer 20 minutes after I posted mine?

Comment: @RoshanBhumbra In there anyone can post the answer :)  so please don't worry about that.ok

Comment: I know, it just seems a bit redundant

Comment: @RoshanBhumbra seems u too envy ☺

Comment: Don't worry, there's nothing to be envious of

Comment: @RoshanBhumbra if u want i will delete my answer.no problem ☺

Comment: calm down guys :)

Answer (score 0):

With experience from this from my past, I have too had this problem and its simple. Your image tag is this ...

`<img id="avatar" width="100" height="100" src="image/avatar.jpg"/>`

In the `src` portion of the `img` tag you have the **slashes slanted to the wrong direction that is if you are getting your images from your computer** but if it is in the internet you have it all right but missing one part like Roshan Bhumbra stated.

If you are getting the image from your PC then do the following. Note that the slash at the beginning does not apply to the path of the image on your PC...

`<img id="avatar" width="100" height="100" src="image\avatar.jpg"/>`

If the image is on the internet do as Roshan Bhumbra said...

`<img id="avatar" width="100" height="100" src="/image/avatar.jpg"/>`

J.Carter :)

Answer (score -1):

add `~/` before path like

```
<img id="avatar" width="100" height="100" src="~/image/avatar.jpg"/>
```